# java.util.Base64 cannot be resolved with OpenJ9

Tags: java

java.util.Base64 cannot be resolved
This error comes with when I started using OpenJ9.

How to resolve this with this version of java

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have, the full error message you get and the description of your system.

Comment: More like a JDK >8 thing: see [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html). That "J9" does not alude to a java version; that could still be java 7 - without Base64.

Answer (score 1):

As mention [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/jsr335-pr/api/api/java/util/Base64.html), java.util.Base64 is available from Java 1.8. If you are using an older version of java then please update it to at least Java-8.
I have tried with the following configuration and found it working:
java: openJdk11
JVM: openj9

Downloaded from: https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=openj9

Java code: 
App.java

```
import java.util.Base64;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encode("Hello".getBytes()));
    }
}
```

output:

[B@8f17baab

Compiled:

```
$jdk-11.0.1+13/Contents/Home/bin/javac ~/Desktop/App.java
```

Run:

```
$jdk-11.0.1+13/Contents/Home/bin/java App
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently we have migrated our application from JDK 1.8 to JDK 10. We have used the open source library - http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/ which is really good and working fine.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, it might be a fallback solution. Though the java.util.Base64 is very versatile, with _many_ variations, and stems from a historical effort to consolidate several Base64 methods that at that time existed in java (iavax.mail etcetera). It would be sad, not to be able to use java.util.Base64.